# How to use file_get_contents or file_get_html?

Tags: php, file-get-contents, simple-html-dom

I've read through quite a few questions on here and I'm not sure if I should be using `file_get_contents` or `file_get_html` for this.

All that I'm trying to do is use PHP to display the two tables from this page on my website:  http://www.statmyweb.com/recently-analyzed/

I know how to get their full page and display it on my site of course, but I can't figure out how I'm able to just pull those two tables without also getting the header/footer.

Comment: @Mark Baker, the simple-html-dom tag might have been a good clue

Comment: @pguardiario - true, I should have noticed that

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are not able to specify in `file_get_contents()` just to retrieve the tables.

You would have to get the return value of `file_get_contents()` using:

```
$result = file_get_contents("urlHere");
```

And then analyse the `$result` variable and extract what information you need to output.

Answer (score 33):

You want `file_get_html` because `file_get_contents` will load the response body into a string but `file_get_html` will load it into simple-html-dom.

```
$dom = file_get_html($url);
$tables = $dom->find('table');
echo $tables[0];
echo $tables[1];
```

Alternatively you could use `file_get_contents` along with `str_get_html`:

```
$dom = str_get_html(file_get_contents($url));
```

But that would be silly.

Comment: how can you cover $dom in string,which have similar string which we can get by file_get_content or  do we any other function like file_get_content to get string from $dom

Comment: Normally, it would be silly.  Except perhaps you can't use either file_get_contents or file_get_html because of limitations (eg allow_url_fopen is off) In which case you are going to probably collect the string with curl and then use str_get_html.  Not really the OPs question but it might help someone ....

Answer (score 0):

Take the full website content by `file_get_contents()`, then apply preg_match on the content you have got with `<table>` and `</table>`. This will bring you all the contents under the table tags. While showing it in your web page, just put a `<table>` then echo your matched content and a `</table>` at the end.

Comment: +1 This would be painful (especially when a tool like simple_html_dom is available), but would definitely work.

Comment: It will work for this specific example, but it will fail on certain other cases, like when there is a nested ```table``` element inside a ```table```

Comment: As previously mentioned,  regex functions represent a suboptimal tool for the task.