# Error during a preg_match_all in PHP

Tags: php, preg-match

I need to check if a string contains a particular words.

My code is the following:

```
// Get index.html source
$html = file_get_contents('extract/index.html');

// Bad words checker
$badWords = array("iframe", "alert");
$matches = array();
$matchFound = preg_match_all("/\b(" . implode($badWords,"|") . ")\b/i", $html, $matches);

if ($matchFound) {
    $words = array_unique($matches[0]);
    foreach($words as $word) {
        $results[] = array('Error' => "Keyword found : ". $word);
    }
}
else {
    $results[] = array('Success' => "No keywords found.");
}
```

Each time I want to execute this, I have the following warning:

```
Warning: preg_match_all(): Unknown modifier 'w' in /home/public_html/upload.php on line 131
```

Line 131:

```
$matchFound = preg_match_all("/\b(" . implode($badWords,"|") . ")\b/i", $html, $matches);
```

Do you know why ?

Thanks.

Comment: Update your code so you can output the regular expression and see what it *really* is at runtime.

Comment: `implode($badWords,"|")` is the problem.

Comment: @AbraCadaver The arguments are in the [wrong order](http://php.net/implode).

Comment: `Note: implode() can, for historical reasons, accept its parameters in either order. For consistency with explode(), however, it may be less confusing to use the documented order of arguments.`

Comment: I'm sure if you echo what that regex evaluates to, you will have a good idea where the problem lies.

Comment: var_dump your implode($badWords,"|");

Comment: The var_dump gave me : string(266).

Comment: and the contents of the string ?

Comment: It's a HTML page code (`file_get_contents('extract/index.html')`).

Comment: Is `file_get_html` is a official PHP function? I do not find any doc on it.

Comment: `file_get_html()` is not a PHP built in function. @Opentuned http://stackoverflow.com/q/14962359/ - http://stackoverflow.com/a/14970732/ <= custom function.

Comment: Apologies, I misread another article, this has a few suggestions: http://htmlparsing.com/php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If one of the bad words is '/w', it can cause this problem. The example below demonstrates this:

```
$html = 'foobar';

// Bad words checker
$badWords = array("iframe", "alert", '/w');
$matches = array();
$matchFound = preg_match_all("/\b(" . implode($badWords,"|") . ")\b/i", $html, $matches);
```

Variations of '/w' such as 'foo/wbar' or '/wfoo' would also cause this issue. Go through the badWords and remove the problematic ones.

Edit: Another solution is to  use a different delimiter like #. Like this:

```
$matchFound = preg_match_all("#\b(" . implode($badWords,"|") . ")\b#i", $html, $matches);
```

Comment: You get it! I will accept your answer in few moments! Thanks!